# MPAndroidChart - issues with setVisibleYRange, does not work for setting higher values

Tags: android, view, charts, mpandroidchart

Working with MPandroiChart i have encounterd a problem, i am adding dynamical data and am trying to have the chart fit the highest data at all times, using "setVisibleYRange()" seems to work fine when i need to narrow down the view but does not seem to work when i need the view to expand again after narrowing it down, based on the mpandroidChart example i have made a simple test activity that shows my point:

```
    public class DynamicalAddingActivityTest extends Activity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {

    private LineChart mChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linechart_noseekbar);

        mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mChart.setDescription("");





          // add an empty data object
            mChart.setData(new LineData());
    //        mChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
    //        mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        mChart.invalidate();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            addEntry();
        }

        mChart.setVisibleYRange(2, AxisDependency.LEFT);
        mChart.invalidate();

        findViewById(R.id.add).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addEntry();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.change).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
                int vis = Integer.valueOf(t.getText().toString());
                mChart.setVisibleYRange(vis, AxisDependency.LEFT);
                mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mChart.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    int[] mColors = ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS;

    private void addEntry() {

        LineData data = mChart.getData();

        if(data != null) {

            LineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
            // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well

            if (set == null) {
                set = createSet();
                data.addDataSet(set);
            }

            // add a new x-value first
            data.addXValue(set.getEntryCount() + "");

            // choose a random dataSet
            int randomDataSetIndex = (int) (Math.random() * data.getDataSetCount());

            data.addEntry(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 10), set.getEntryCount()), randomDataSetIndex);

            // let the chart know it's data has changed
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

//            mChart.setVisibleXRange(6);
//            mChart.setVisibleYRange(30, AxisDependency.LEFT);
//            
//            // this automatically refreshes the chart (calls invalidate())
//            mChart.moveViewTo(data.getXValCount()-7, 55f, AxisDependency.LEFT);

            // redraw the chart
            mChart.invalidate();   
        }
    }

    private void removeLastEntry() {

        LineData data = mChart.getData();

        if(data != null) {

            LineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

            if (set != null) {

                Entry e = set.getEntryForXIndex(set.getEntryCount() - 1);

                data.removeEntry(e, 0);
                // or remove by index
                // mData.removeEntry(xIndex, dataSetIndex);

                mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mChart.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addDataSet() {

        LineData data = mChart.getData();

        if(data != null) {

            int count = (data.getDataSetCount() + 1);

            // create 10 y-vals
            ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();

            if(data.getXValCount() == 0) {
                // add 10 x-entries
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    data.addXValue("" + (i+1));
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < data.getXValCount(); i++) {
                yVals.add(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 50f) + 50f * count, i));
            }

            LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet " + count);
            set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
            set.setCircleSize(4.5f);

            int color = mColors[count % mColors.length];

            set.setColor(color);
            set.setCircleColor(color);
            set.setHighLightColor(color);
            set.setValueTextSize(10f);
            set.setValueTextColor(color);

            data.addDataSet(set);
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();   
        }
    }

    private void removeDataSet() {

        LineData data = mChart.getData();

        if(data != null) {

            data.removeDataSet(data.getDataSetByIndex(data.getDataSetCount() - 1));

            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dynamical, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actionAddEntry:
                addEntry();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Entry added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.actionRemoveEntry:
                removeLastEntry();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Entry removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.actionAddDataSet:
                addDataSet();
                Toast.makeText(this, "DataSet added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.actionRemoveDataSet:
                removeDataSet();
                Toast.makeText(this, "DataSet removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.actionAddEmptyLineData:
                mChart.setData(new LineData());
                mChart.invalidate();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Empty data added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.actionClear:
                mChart.clear();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Chart cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private LineDataSet createSet() {

        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "DataSet 1");
        set.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        set.setCircleSize(4.5f);
        set.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 99, 99));
        set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 99, 99));
        set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(190, 190, 190));
        set.setAxisDependency(AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);

        return set;
    }
}
```

with this xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="change"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:id="@+id/change"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="add"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            />

        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:id="@+id/edit"/>



    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

So, when i try to type in a value greater then the one i have set before "setVisibleYRange()" does not seem to work, however it does work if a set a value lower then the one set before.

any ideas on why this is? am i missing something?
@PhilJay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing something.

This is not a "zoom" method. It's only purpose is to **restrain the maximum visible range of values** displayed on the y-axis.

If the current visible range is 100, and then `setVisibleYRange(50)` is called, the visible range will be reduced to 50 since the current range of 100 is no longer allowed. If then `setVisibleYRange(100)` is called, nothing has to change, because the current visible range of 50 is well in the allowed bounds. If you then start zooming out, it will stop at range 100.

Comment: I understand now, thank you, I will ask a more clear question.